# Convert optional string to Int64

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, dictionary

I am trying to convert an optional string to a string and then to an Int64.

```
 let number = blog["number"] as! String
print(Int64(number))
```

The problem is that the "number" key is an optional string so it crashes when going to Int64. I have a couple methods to remove the optional type but none worked.

Comment: How is `blog` declared?

Comment: `as!` means "please crash me". You got what you asked for.

Comment: What does `print(blog["number"]!.dynamicType)` print?

Comment: it prints __NSCFString

Answer (score 1):

```
guard let string = blog["number"] as? String else {
    /* Not a string, handle error here */
    return 
}

guard let number = Int64(string) else {
    /* string isn't an Int64, handle error here */
    return
}

//use number here
```

You can also use `if let` to do the unwrapping, if you'd rather not exit your function. It's not as pretty though:

```
if let string = blog["number"] as? String else {
    if let let number = Int64(string) {
        //use number here
    }
    else {
        /* string isn't an Int64, handle error here */
    }
}
else {
    /* Not a string, handle error here */
}
```

Comment: I implemented your second solution and the string is still optional if let string = blog["number"] as? String {
                                if let  number = Int64(string) {
                                    phoneNumberArray.addObject(PhoneNumberObject(type:(blog["type"] as? String)! , number:number))
                                }
                            }

Comment: Are you sure? And don't use the second solution, it was just an example to show how `if let` can be used. Use `guard` whenever possible instead.

Comment: I used the first solution and it fails. The variable string is still optional when it gets to the second check.

Comment: Check in the debugger, what does is the value of `blog["number"]` ?

Comment: (lldb) po blog["number"]
▿ Optional<AnyObject>
  - Some : Optional(15612524857)

(lldb)

Comment: It's a nested optional? What is the json string that defines this?

Comment: I am not sure what you means by what is the nested string that defines it. This is pulled from a dictionary made from my json response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116513/discussion-between-amomchilov-and-user1079052).

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can make use of `NSNumberFormatter` (specifically, the computed property `longLongValue`) from `Foundation`:

```
import Foundation

let dict = ["number": "500"]

if let str = dict["number"], 
   let num = NSNumberFormatter().numberFromString(str)?.longLongValue {

    /* 'num' is Int64 representation of 'dict["number"]', and we
        reach this scope only if it exists and can validly be
        represented as an Int64 number */
}
```